# Delete query optimization

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a delete query who work well with small amount of row. But now with about 80K row it's failling due to "timeout"

My two table are like that :

```
TableA
------

| Column     | type       |
|------------|------------|
| link_id    | bigint(40) |
| product_id | int(10)    |
| parent_id  | int(10)    |

Table B
-------

| Column    | type    |
|-----------|---------|
| id        | int(11) |
| parent_id | int(11) |
| child_id  | int(11) |
```

I do a query like that to make a delete

```
DELETE FROM TABLEA
WHERE link_id IN (
    SELECT link_id FROM (
        SELECT link_id, parent_id, product_id FROM TABLEA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, parent_id, child_id FROM TABLEB
    ) tbl
    GROUP BY parent_id, product_id
    HAVING count(*) = 1
    ORDER BY parent_id
) ;
```

But whould not be the most optimized one.

The goal is to delete from table A all records not present in table B
for the couple "parent_id / child_id".

in Table A the column "product_id" is the "child_id".

Thanks

Comment: what indexes are on these tables? What does `EXPLAIN {query}` show?

Comment: You don't need to **ORDER BY**  the subquery

Comment: For table A index Index

PRIMARY link_id
UNIQUE product_id, parent_id
INDEX parent_id

And table B

there is only an index on
PRIMARY id

Comment: How small is the _small amount of row_? Could you do `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem

```
DELETE A  FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN 
(    SELECT link_id FROM 
    (
        SELECT link_id, parent_id, product_id FROM TABLEA
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, parent_id, child_id FROM TABLEB
    ) tbl
    GROUP BY parent_id, product_id
    HAVING count(*) = 1)B
ON A.link_id=B.link_id
where   A.link_id is not null;
```

Comment: I got an error (I'm on mariadb) and cant change the "sql_mode" option...

`Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tbl.link_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: change you sql_mode through command or config file https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12084/getting-this-sql-error-group-by-incompatible-with-sql-mode-only-full-group-by/12106  and also check index on Link_id

Comment: There are a lot of posts in SO explaining why `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is necessary. This is one > https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115425/10910692 . But if you only disable it temporarily just to perform the `DELETE`, why not.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `NOT EXISTS` to get the link_id that don't have any relation in tableb

```
DELETE FROM TABLEA
WHERE link_id IN (SELECT link_id 
                  FROM TABLEA a
                  where not exists (select link_id 
                                    from tableb b
                                    where b.parent_id=a.parent_id and b.child_id=a.product_id))
```

Comment: with that one I gon an error : You can't specify target table 'TABLEA' for update in FROM clause